# How can add woocommerce product caption in single product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-rest-api

I want when I go single product page that time main image caption automictic show on below the image and when i change thumbnail that time thumbnail image caption is show on main image .

Shortly, thumbnail wise caption will be change

I have only function.php file access.

I have code but this is static caption of main image.

```
function add_caption_below_product_image() {

    echo '<p style="text-align: center;" class="image-caption">';
    $caption = get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id() )->post_excerpt;
    echo $caption;
    echo '</p>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'add_caption_below_product_image' );
```

Can you help me ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0kVT.png)

Thumbnail wise caption will be change on main image

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. The filter that runs for every image is `woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html` but it receives HTML that you need to modify. Usually I replace the last `</div>` with  `{caption html} . </div>`.

A basic version would be:

```
function add_caption_below_product_image( $html, $attachment_id ) {

    $caption_html = '<p style="text-align: center;" class="image-caption">';
    // this should be escaped for output
    $caption_html .= esc_html( get_post( $attachment_id )->post_excerpt ); 
    
    $caption_html .= '</p>';

    // now you need to add it before the last </div>
    $html = preg_replace( '~<\/div>$~', $caption_html . '</div>', $html );

    return $html;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'add_caption_below_product_image', 10, 2 );
```

I'm the author of the (paid) [Gallery Captions for WooCommerce](https://woo.com/products/gallery-captions-for-woocommerce) extension and this is the basic approach I use in that extension, and so far it works pretty well. The main issue you might run into is if your theme does something weird with the gallery you may need take extra steps.